# Reference kendo grid row id on jQuery href

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core, kendo-grid, razor-pages

I'm currently using Kendo Grid for ASP.Net Core MVC.

So, I created a column with a group of options.

```
columns.Template("<div class='btn-group'></div>")
                            .Title("").Width(100);
```

Then with jquery:

```
    $(this).find(".btn-group").append("<button type='button' class='btn btn-light btn-sm dropdown-toggle' data-bs-toggle='dropdown' aria-expanded='false'>Actions<i class='mdi mdi-chevron-down'></i>. 
   </button>
<ul class='dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end'>
    <li>
       <a href='advertisers/edit/@Html.Raw(Model.Select(x => x.AdvertiserId));'>
       <button class='dropdown-item' type='button'>Edit</button></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <button class='dropdown-item text-danger' type='button'>Mark Inactive</button>
    </li>
</ul>");
```

As you can see I have a button Edit pass the Model.Id from the referenced model, I tried:

```
@Html.Raw(Model.Select(x => x.AdvertiserId))
```

Or

```
@Model.Select(x => x.AdvertiserId)
```

When I try this the URL shows as:

> edit/System.Linq.Enumerable+SelectListIterator%602[Lib.Models.Advertiser,System.Int32];

But none of them works; how can I get this done? Regards

**UPDATE:**

I added the Id as a hidden column:

```
 columns.Bound(x => x.AdvertiserId)
        .Hidden();
```

So I can access all of them with jQuery as: `dataItem.AdvertiserId`

How can I add it on each row `<a href='advertisers/edit/'>` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass an array into query,try to use:

```
<a href='advertisers/edit@(Html.Raw("?AdvertiserId="+String.Join("&AdvertiserId=", Model.Select(x => x.AdvertiserId).ToArray())))'>
       <button class='dropdown-item' type='button'>Edit</button></a>
```

And use action like this:

```
public IActionResult edit(int[] AdvertiserId){
    ...
}
```

Comment: I just want to return selected row advertiserId no an array

Comment: I also tried edit/@Model.Select(x => x.AdvertiserId).First(), but this return always the same Id, because it's first not the selected row id

Answer (score 0):

I fix this by adding the Url as a constant like:

```
 const advertiserEditUrl = 'advertisers/edit?advertiserId=' + dataItem.AdvertiserId;
```

Then in href

```
<a href='"+ advertiserEditUrl +"'></a>
```